# Jodd BeanUtilBean doesn't support java.util.Set?

Tags: java, jodd

I've a bean that contains a java.util.Set, when I try to populate the Set, I got `BeanException: Index property is not an array, list or map`. Why Jodd doesn't support Set ?
My bean look like:

```
public class ShippingRule {
   private Set<String> returnConstraints;

   public Set<String> getReturnConstraints() {
      return returnConstraints;
   }
   public void setReturnConstraints(Set<String> returnConstraints) {
      this.returnConstraints = returnConstraints;
   }
}
```

and I populate the with:

```
ShippingRule shippingRule = new ShippingRule();
BeanUtil.setPropertyForced(shippingRule, "returnConstraints[0]", "restrict1");
BeanUtil.setPropertyForced(shippingRule, "returnConstraints[1]", "restrict2");
```

am I missing something ? Please advise and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Collection`s do not have key/value or index behavior or `get()` method. Let's look your example:

`getProperty("returnConstraints")` returns a `Set<String>`. In that case, what would be the `[0]` on the `Set`? `Set` simply can not be used like this :)

Your example looks like your property has to be `String[]` or `List<String>` or (unlikely) `Map<Integer, String>`.